# Different formatting for certain questions

Tags: support, tagging

I just remarked that some of the questions on the main page are formatted differently than others. All questions which have been tagged with `biblatex` have a yellow background. Is this a new feature or just a browser issue?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may be that you favorited [biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex), as Martin explained, but it also can be that you just happened to *visit* a lot of questions with the [biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex) tag: you can have *implicit* "frequented" tags. See this post on meta.SO for more details: [Why are “etymology” questions on german.sx highlighted for me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96389)

Comment: This is more likely the case, the Frequented Tags issue.

Comment: Yes. Now I see it. The [tag:biblatex]-tag is listed as "frequented" tags. Thanks.

Comment: @Thorsten: Where can I find my list of frequented tags?

Comment: @doncherry Sorry, but I don't know. I think that I wanted to write "... seems to be listed as a ...". I don't think that there's a possibility to get a list of those frequented tags.

Answer (score 7):

Questions tagged with your favorite tags are highlighted. It look to me that your favored [biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex).

Answer (score 3):

Further to @Martin's answer: Tags can be *favourited* by hovering over the tag and clicking the star (the number of users who have favourited a specific tag is given in terms of the *follower count*):

[image: Tags being favourited]

Clicking the star again *ignores* posts with this tag (displaying the posts as almost being transparent/faded). Clicking a third time sets the tag back to *normal* in terms of its appearance.

Another way of accessing your tag favourites is under your user profile. Click on the **prefs** "tab" to view your "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags". The usage and manipulation is very similar to adding tags to regular posts, and therefore should be straight forward.

[image: Tags under profile]

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers. Favoring tags is one way to watch and highlight certain preferred content on Stack Exchange. The two other ways to watch content that I can think of is favoring questions (i.e. your favorite questions) and subscribing to tags by either e-mail (the subscribe link in the hover of tags) or rss (the rss link in the hover of tags).