# why are some questions highlighted in the main questions list?

Tags: support, bookmarks, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different formatting for certain questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/different-formatting-for-certain-questions)

i've noticed that some questions, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41261/mathop-shifts-the-baseline-declaremathoperator-doesnt) on the main site are shaded, and haven't found an answer to "why?"; since i haven't been keeping track, i'm not sure whether the highlighting disappears after a while, but i have the impression that it does. (also wonder why, if true.)

Comment: Usually, the highlighting shouldn't disappear. It could happen though if the tag you've subscribed to (= favorited) is removed because someone thought it wasn't appropriate for the respective question.

Answer (score 5):

Questions tagged with one of your favorite tags are highlighted like this. You can add and remove these with the form at the upper right side of the question list page.

Comment: You can find an overview of your favorited and ignored tags at http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/579 (other users will have to replace `579` by their user ID).

Comment: there's just one problem with this explanation -- i haven't marked any tags as favorites, although it's a fact that i do look at certain ones preferentially.  (i haven't marked any to be ignored either.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I see. It seems that you can have implicit favorite tags. See the thread linked by Thorsten above. It looks like a duplicate to me now.

Comment: agreed it's a duplicate.  i didn't spot the linked thread earlier, even though i did search for "highlight". (it's there, i just overlooked it.  sorry for the noise.)