# What do these red-colored post entries mean?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different formatting for certain questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/different-formatting-for-certain-questions)

Occasionally I see post entries colored in dim red on the main page, as show below:

[image]

What does the coloring mean?

Link to the question: [Doing an interlinear text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45520/doing-an-interlinear-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this question on MSO: [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22184/176533)

Does that question contains one of your *favorited* tags?

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyVihrov No problem! :)